# Discontinued for loop Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

is there a way to make two ranges in for loop. I have to check lets say 10 arrays between each other, but if array1 is picked it shouldn't check with itself.
If array1 is picked then array1 should be checked with arrays2-10. if 2nd is picked it should be checked with array1 and array3-10.

I found a chain function but it doesn't seem to work properly in my case or I do something wrong.

```
for i in range (1,11): 
    test_array is picked 
    for j in chain(range(1,i),range(i+1,11)):
        does the check between test_array and all the other arrays Excluding the one picked as test_array

for i in range(1,11):
   pick test_array
       for j in range (1,11):
           if (j==i):
                 continue
             ....
```

this peace according to the tests compares array1 with itself
the above code works for 2 for loops but I have nested more than 3 and with continue it goes all the way down, which is not I want
Thanks

Found the answer I was looking for :

```
for i in range(1,11):
    do something.
    for j in range(1,i) + range((i+1),11): 
        do something
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are looking for, please provide some examples.

Comment: I want to make for loop that excludes certain number from the loop. for example if 2 is picked it should go like this (1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and so on, hope that makes it clearer

Comment: why not add `if j == i: continue` instead?

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools.combinations()`:

```
import itertools
arrays = [[x] for x in 'abcd']
# [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']]

for pair in itertools.combinations(arrays, 2):
    print pair # or compare, or whatever you want to do with this pair
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) here:

```
import itertools as IT
from math import factorial

lists = [[1, 2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
n = len(lists)
for c in IT.islice(IT.permutations(lists, n), 0, None, factorial(n-1)):
    current = c[0]
    rest = c[1:]
    print current, rest
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2] ([3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6])
[3, 4] ([1, 2], [4, 5], [5, 6])
[4, 5] ([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6])
[5, 6] ([1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5])
```

---

And another way using slicing:

```
lists = [[1, 2], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]]
n = len(lists)
for i, item in enumerate(lists):
    rest = lists[:i] + lists[i+1:]
    print item, rest
```